# i have a div in an a,but how can i trigger event on div and prevent the event on <a>?

Tags: events, propagation

this is my first question on stack,i am not good at English,sorry for that.

my code can't stop  jumping when i click the div.
list is a div contains some details.
my js:

```
function clickList(e)
{
    var listAll=e.parentNode.childNodes;
    var list=listAll[1];
    console.log(list);
    if (list.style.display == "none")
    {  
        list.style.display = "block";    
    }
    else
    {    
        list.style.display = "none";    
    } 
    e.stopPropagation();    
}
```

my html:

```
<a href="an address">
  <div class="pull-right" onclick="clickList(this)">
    <i class="iconfont">&#xe60a;</i>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are stopping the event propagation, you can just have javascript:void() as below in href instead of address:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
  <div class="pull-right" onclick="clickList(this)">
  <i class="iconfont">&#xe60a;</i>
  </div>
</a>
```

Also Remove e.stopPropagation();  in clickList as this will be the div object and not an event object.

Comment: I find my fault. Maybe  I nested too much. Anyway thank you.